# Overriding function from another class

Tags: actionscript-3, apache-flex

I am defining this function in one of my classes:

```
public function onUse():void {};
```

Then in another of my classes (let's call it "class2"), I create a object of this class, and then want to override this function with another one. After some Google-Fu, I have found this, and used it...

```
button.onUse {
    variable = value;
}
```

...but it executes instantly, and not when onUse() is called - which seems to be an empty function, always.

I didn't find anything more than that - I tried a few things myself, like specifying a function inside class2 and using `button.onUse = function();`, but it always throws errors.

Can anyone tell me whether what I am trying to do is actually possible, and if it is, how can I do it?

Comment: This is a really basic Object Oriented Programming notion. It's alright, we all have to start somewhere. I suggest you document yourself on the subject though so that you can start on solid ground. I however do not have any good reference to start with but I'm pretty sure a good samaritan here does have some really nice ones to share.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can only override functions when you are extending the class:

```
public class A {
    public function foo():void {
        doStuff();
    }
}

public class B extends A {
    override public function foo():void {
        doOtherStuff();
    }
}

var n:A = new A(); 
n.foo(); // => calls doStuff();

var o:B = new B();
o.foo(); // => calls doOtherStuff();
```

Hence, assigning a different function to a class method of an instance is not possible at runtime.

You can, however, let your original class contain a *field of type `Function`*, and then simply assign a different closure to it.

```
public class A {
    public var foo:Function;
}

var n:A = new A();
n.foo = function ():void { 
    doStuff();
};
n.foo(); // => calls doStuff();

var o:A = new A();
o.foo = function ():void {
    doOtherStuff();
}
o.foo(); // => calls doOtherStuff();
```

Answer (score 0):

check the syntax of

```
button.onUse {
    variable = value;
}
```

a function would be defined as

public function onUse():void {};

and overwritten with

```
override public function onUse():void {
}
```

in a different class

the way you're trying to do it, does not constitute overriding a function.

What I've done in similar circumstances is create a onClickFunction function in the class

```
public var onClickFunction:Function = null;
```

and then in the CLICK event listener function add

```
if(onClickFunction != null){
    onClickFunction();
}
```

then you can assign your on-click functionality by doing something like this

button.onClickFunction = function():void{
    variable = value;
    // dostuff
}

this is not the best way of doing it, but probably the easiest way of implementing the functionality. And ideally you'd use inheritance the way the spacepirate suggested.